# Orlando International airport - can you get from terminal A to B while inside security?

Tags: usa, airports, mco

My friends and I are flying out of MCO (Orlando International Airport in FL in the USA). One friend and I are on JetBlue and will likely have a gate in section 1 in Terminal A, where the other friend is on Delta and will likely be in section 4 in Terminal B.

The other friend has a later flight than ours. Can she join us at our gate until our flight leaves, then go to her gate while only going through security once?

It's unclear from the [map](https://www.orlandoairports.net/getting-around-mco/) if you need to "choose" a gate to go through security through, or if the gates are connected beyond security.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used to live in Orlando and have flown in & out of MCO a number of times, so I can assure you that the [MCO terminal map](https://fr.orlandoairports.net/getting-around-mco/) is a little simplistic and doesn't really show you how the trams between the main terminal building and the outlying gate wings actually work.

If you're in the main terminal and pass through security, you will reach the outgoing trams for whichever side you going to.

If you're in one of the gate wings and get on to the tram to the main terminal, you do not exit the tram at a point 'behind' security which would allow you to board the other tram to the other wing - you exit straight into the main terminal building.

So in order to get to one of the other wings you would have to pass back through the security checkpoint - even if you're going back out to the other wing on the same side.

So to answer your question - unfortunately no that won't be possible - your friend would have to pass through security twice - if they even let her do so since her departing flight is on the other side.

Answer (score 6):

Terminal A and B are just the two sides of the building; the doors (and airline counters) on the north are called A and the doors (and airline counters) on the south side are called B. You can just walk around in the building, once inside, the difference does no longer exist.

However, there are two ends - west and east - of the building, where you ride on trains (called APMs ‘automated People Movers’) to four different gate areas - two per side.
Both ends have their own security, the west side is gates 1 to 69, and the east side is 70 to 129. You can freely walk between the gates on the west side; on the east side, you cannot ride one train back and the other forth, because international arrvivals come through the gates 70 to 99, and if you return in the train from gates 70 to 99, you must leave the secure area.

Note that you also cannot go in the secure area in the east if your ticket is for the west, and vice versa.

From your description, and from where I know the two airlines have their gates, you will not be able to walk between those gates without passing through security again - if you ever make it in on the ‘wrong’ side.

Answer (score 3):

You can get into the secure area on the opposite side..I did so by explaining my Airline Lounge (United) is on the other side from Gate 97 where Air Canada leaves from. It did take a half hour to get back to the correct side of security for my departure, and could be longer if security is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at maps at the Orlando airport site https://fr.orlandoairports.net/getting-around-mco/, and doing some research, it seems that there are two sides of the airport.  It appears sections 1 and 3 can be accessed behind security on one side, and sections 2 and 4 can be accessed behind security on the other side.

If you go through the same security gates (west or east) as the other does, then you'll be able to visit each other and change gates while remaining behind security.

Comment: Yes, but since 1 and 4 are on opposite sides, I don't think it's possible to go between them without leaving the secure area.

Comment: @ZachLipton That's my understanding as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just did this yesterday. Went to A5x with my friends and then went to B2x for my flight. Went through TSA together.