# Connecting flight in MCO airport

Tags: layovers, short-connections, mco

We will fly from SFO to MCO on United Airlines. From there we will take Bahamasair to Nassau (NAS). I appreciate any advice: Is 2 hours enough to move from an arrival gate in airside 3, go thru East TSA, then get to a departure gate in airside 4?

Comment: Standard question #1: is this a single ticket/booking or two different tickets/booking ? Standard question #2: do you have checked baggage or only carry on ?

Comment: 1: Two different booking. 2: Only carry-on.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MCO airport - can you get from terminal A to B while inside security?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/mco-airport-can-you-get-from-terminal-a-to-b-while-inside-security)

Answer (score 3):

United Airlines flies out of Airside 3, whereas Bahamasair flies out of Airside 4. Airsides 1 and 3 are on the west side of the terminal building, behind one set of security checkpoints, and Airsides 2 and 4 are on the east side of the terminal building, behind another set of security checkpoints, so to move from Airside 3 to 4, you will have to leave security and go through security again.

Comment: Please also note that because you have booked the trips on different tickets, if you miss the Bahamasair flight because your inbound flight is late, it will be your responsibility (task-wise and financially) to book a replacement flight.  Because of this risk, a much longer connection tie than two hours is strongly recommended.  If you book the entire trip on one airline, it will have a duty to transport you as soon as practicable if your inbound flight is delayed or cancelled.