# Domestic to International Arrivals at MCO

Tags: airports, mco

I'm flying to Orlando from NY (Domestic) and my mom is flying to Orlando from Panama (International) on the same day.  Can I go from domestic to international terminal to meet her at her gate? if not, is there a central point I can wait for her that will be easy for her to find? thank you!

Comment: You will definitely not be able to meet her at the gate, since she will have to go through immigration & customs before being allowed into the the rest of the terminal.  I'm not familiar with MCO, but outside customs is probably your best bet.

Comment: It's highly unlikely. If you see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/mco-airport-can-you-get-from-terminal-a-to-b-while-inside-security) you'll see that, unless you're arriving in the same 'quadrant', you won't be able to meet up until you both arrive at the main terminal building.