# Time for domestic to international connection at Orlando/MCO

Tags: short-connections, connecting-flights, airport-terminals, mco

I am flying from San Francisco (SFO) to Orlando (MCO) and connecting to Peru. The inbound flight will likely be in section 2 (terminal A) and outbound in section 4 (terminal B). The layover time I have is 1 hour and 52 minutes. Does it sound safe enough? It seems like I need to get through another checkpoint at the main terminal.

Note: I'll have carry-on baggage only, and I booked my flights with one airline (through American Airlines, but the inbound flight is with Alaska and the outbound with Latam).

Comment: Please when you talk about airports, it would be nice to add the full names so people do not need to look them up. (Or at least understand which part of the worlds you talk about.)

Comment: Which airlines are involved? Having booked with the same airline is good, but if you have to change terminals you'll need to exit security and reenter. That can be a major hassle, depending on what time of day and year you're there. During spring break, for instance, that may be a bit tight.

Comment: Inbound Alaska, outbound Latam. I am traveling on June 19, Friday. Arriving at 12:32 and departing at 14:25 local time.

Comment: @cbw: "AS and LA are in different terminals, so you will need to exit security." Not true. Alaska gates are in Airside 2, and LATAM gates are in Airside 4. Airsides 2 and 4 are behind the same security checkpoint, so there is no need to exit security.

Comment: @user102008 I am very confused by the terminal map on the MCO official website. I heard people saying from Airside 2 to Airside 4 is the only transition that needs to go through security check again. Not sure how true it is. It's good to hear you say that. Are you positive that I do not need to go through the security check?

Comment: @user102008 That's my fault. I looked at the map wrong. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Since USA doesn't have exit emigration check, you can make the domestic to international connection easily within that time, provided the incoming flights are not delayed. You will be provided with boarding pass for the both segment and your bags will be checked through (if any).

Familiarize with the layout of the airport here - https://www.orlandoairports.net/getting-around-mco/ so that you can find out

Note that the reverse connection might be difficult in that time, as you have to clear immigration, collect bags and check-in again.

Comment: A side note - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/mco-airport-can-you-get-from-terminal-a-to-b-while-inside-security?rq=1